# arrows arranging on a ring

Tags: graphics

I have been involved in a challenge for some time: A ring with a number of arrows on its perimeter. The number of arrows depends on the angle $\theta$. For example, for $\theta=2\pi/36$, the number of arrows is `36`.
Moreover, the angle between any neighbors is exactly $\theta$. I'm very weak at using graphs and do not know what the starting point is. Any idea can be welcome...

[image]

Based on the @flinty post and @cvgmt I Updated the image.
Then I can say that I wish to have cvgmt's image as the below one.
Please look the new desired blue arrows.
I wish to have blue arrows that drawn by me with paint.

[image]

Comment: Do you want the arrows to spin around their normal? I have done this in my answer.

Comment: If I understand correctly you have 2 angles, theta, which is the angle describing the position on the circle, and alpha which is the angle by which the arrow is rotated around the radius vector? You want to do this such that alpha = theta?

Answer (score 7):

```
n = 36;
len = .25;
points2d = N[CirclePoints[n]];
points3d = Append[#, 0] & /@ points2d;
tangents3d = Append[#, 0] & /@ (Cross /@ points2d);

arrows = MapThread[Arrow[{#1 - len #2, #1 + len #2}] &,
 {points3d, tangents3d}];

(* spin the arrows as we go around the circle *)
arrowsRotated = MapIndexed[
   With[{i = First[#2]},
     With[{p = points3d[[i]]},
      Rotate[#1, 2 Pi (i - 1)/n, p, p]]] &
   , arrows];

Graphics3D[{{Black, Thick, 
   ResourceFunction["Circle3D"][{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1}, Pi/2, 0]},
  Red, arrowsRotated}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: spinning arrows on a 3d circle]

Comment: thank you so much but they do not rotate in a similar manner

Comment: @Unbelievable what do you mean? Your diagram shows them spinning round.

Comment: @Unbelievable if you just need a fixed angle, then change `2 Pi (i - 1)/n` to whatever fixed number you want.

Comment: I appreciate you again. But if you look at the second picture added, the difference with your form is tangible.

Comment: Your arrows start from one point and are drawn on both sides of the circle.

Comment: @Unbelievable yes but we're looking at it from the other side, so of course the arrow would be pointing in the same direction. Without a twist then yes, it would point in the opposite direction as it went around the circle, but if you twist it 180* then it's going to point in the same direction when pictured as above.

Answer (score 5):

**Reply to the comment**

It means that we need to set `f[s]:=-s` ?

```
R = 8;
r[s_] := R {Cos[s], Sin[s], 0};
n[s_] := -r[s] // Normalize;
t[s_] := r'[s] // Normalize;
b[s_] := Cross[t[s], n[s]] // Normalize;
circle3 = 
  ParametricPlot3D[r[s], {s, 0, 2 π}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.5], Green}];
d = 1;
f[s_] := -s;
Show[{circle3, 
  Table[Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[.01], Arrow[{r[s], r[s] + d*t[s]}], 
     Arrow[{r[s], r[s] + d*b[s]}], Red, 
     Arrow[{r[s] - d*(Cos[θ]*t[s] + Sin[θ]*b[s]), 
        r[s] + d*(Cos[θ]*t[s] + 
            Sin[θ]*b[s])} /. θ -> f[s]]}], {s, 0, 
    2 π, 2 π/36}]}, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> R + 1, 
 ImageSize -> Large, ViewPoint -> {0.60, -2.90, 1.62}]
```

[image]

**Updated**

Here we use Frenet-Serret frame $\{r(s): t(s),n(s),b(s)\}$ and set a rotation speed function `f[s]` so we can adjust such function to get another result.

```
R = 8;
r[s_] := R {Cos[s], Sin[s], 0};
n[s_] := -r[s] // Normalize;
t[s_] := r'[s] // Normalize;
b[s_] := Cross[t[s], n[s]] // Normalize;
circle3 = 
  ParametricPlot3D[r[s], {s, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Green];
d = 2;
f[s_] := s + π/2;
Show[{circle3, 
  Table[Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[.02], Red, 
     Arrow[{r[s] - d*(Cos[θ]*t[s] + Sin[θ]*b[s]), 
        r[s] + d*(Cos[θ]*t[s] + 
            Sin[θ]*b[s])} /. θ -> f[s]]}], {s, 0, 
    2 π, 2 π/36}]}, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> R + 1]
```

[image]

**Original**

We can rotate a line around the z-axis `{0,0,1}` with angle `λ (2 π)/n` where `0<λ<1` ( such line through the point `{1,0,0}` with direction `dir`)

```
n = 36;
λ = 0.8;
sol = NMaximize[{0, 
    VectorAngle[
      RotationTransform[((2 π)/n)*1, {0, 0, 1}][{x, y, z}], 
      RotationTransform[((2 π)/n)*2, {0, 0, 1}][{x, y, 
        z}]] == λ (2 π)/n, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, z > 0, 
    y > 0}, {x, y, z}];
dir = {x, y, z} /. sol[[2]];
circle3 = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
   PlotStyle -> Green];
Show[Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.02], 
   Table[GeometricTransformation[{{Red, PointSize[Large], 
       Point[{1, 0, 0}]}, 
      Arrow[{{1, 0, 0} - .3 dir, {1, 0, 0} + .3 dir}]}, 
     RotationTransform[((2 π)/n)*k, {0, 0, 1}]], {k, n}]}, 
  BoxRatios -> Automatic], circle3, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 ViewPoint -> {-1.39, -2.93, 0.97}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer.  I thought a lot about your answer, but I am ashamed to say that there is a problem with the answer.
I changed the text of the question and painted your shape inside it as desired. I would be so glad if you look at it.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer where the position vectors begin on the circle, rather than their midpoints being on the circle?

Answer (score 1):

Graphics3D[
Table[{Hue[t/(2 [Pi])],
Arrow
[{{Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, {(Cos[t] - Sin[t])/
Sqrt[1 + Cos[t]^2], (Sin[t] + Cos[t])/Sqrt[1 + Cos[t]^2],
Cos[t]/Sqrt[1 + Cos[t]^2]}}]}, {t, 0, 2 [Pi], [Pi]/16}],
Boxed -> False]

[image]